# How to style 4 elements alternatively and repeat using css?

Tags: css

So I have a list of elements and I want them to style accordingly. [image]

As you can see here in the image above I have 4 different colors and if added another element I would expect the color will be red. But am not sure how to do it.

I can't make `:nth-child(1n)` and so on because obviously it will take the other element using that code. I know I can just use `:first-child` but how can apply these colors in the next 4 elements and so on?

To make it clearer of what I wanted to achieve you can refer to this image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to repeat after 4 elements, use `4n` in the `nth-child` selector.

```
li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  color: blue;
}

li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  color: pink;
}

li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/z91rn3p2/)

Answer (score 1):

The formula for `nth-child` is `an+b`, so you can have a color for `nth-child(4n)` (+0), another for `nth-child(4n+1)`, for `nth-child(4n+2)` and for `nth-child(4n+3)`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_formula